# jQuery BBQ Plugin Selector doesn't work

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery-bbq

I'm loading a PHP Page with BBQ Plugin:

```
     $(function(){
 var cache = {
    '': $('.bbq-default')
  };

  $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function() {
    var url = $.param.fragment();
    $( 'a.bbq-current' ).removeClass( 'bbq-current' );
    $( '.bbq-content' ).children( ':visible' ).hide();
    url && $( 'a[href="#' + url + '"]' ).addClass( 'bbq-current' );

    if ( cache[ url ] && url == "") {
      cache[ url ].show();
    } else {
      $('.bbq-loading' ).show();
      cache[ url ] = $( '<div class="bbq-item"/>' )
      .appendTo( '.bbq-content' )
      .load('session.php', {url: url}, function(){
          // Content loaded, hide "loading" content.
          $( '.bbq-loading' ).hide();
        });
   }
  })
  $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
});
```

It's just the example code from the plugin.

With the session.php I have a navigation menu through the different data sets of my MySQL DB. On every side which is loaded via the BBQ Plugin I have a comment field `<textarea id='comment'></textarea>`

I want to submit the input from the textarea with AJAX to my database, but the selector `$("textarea#comment").val();` just works when the page has been initialy loaded with the URL. When I navigate with the links generated of my php file the selector outputs nothing (tested with firebug console) whether I wrote in the textarea or not. (When the value of the textarea is prepopulated the selector works, but not when I change the contents)